# How to add an hyperlink to the content of a cell in excel file?

Tags: django, excel, xlwt

I export my data from database in an excel file:

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype="application/ms-excel")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=Countries.xls'
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('Countries')
ws.write(0, 0, 'Country ID')
ws.write(0, 1, 'Country Name')
index = 1
for country in countries:
    ws.write(index, 1, country.country_id)
    ws.write(index, 1, country.country_name)
    index += 1
wb.save(response)
return response
```

It export my excel file. How to add an hyperlink to the content of a cell  in this file? (`country_name` for example is a link to open a card in browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en-GB#!topic/python-excel/zLMIxnIUwDI):

```
from xlwt import Workbook, Formula

wb = Workbook() 
sheet = wb.add_sheet('testing links') 
link = 'HYPERLINK("http://stackoverflow.com/"; "SO")' 
sheet.write(0, 0, Formula(link))
wb.save('test.xls')
```

Comment: this make the full cell clickable! What about just content of a cell ??

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Will be happy to be wrong though.

Comment: dont wory be happy ! matino make the solution

Comment: Hm, it's pretty much the same as mine solution, isn't it? The whole cell becomes clickable.

Answer (score 1):

```
worksheet.write(index, 1, xlwt.Formula('HYPERLINK("%s";"TITLE")' % country_name))
```